# GKE Ingress with internal load balancer is UNHEALTHY

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, vpc

Here is my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: xxxxxxxx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          protocol: TCP
```

Here is my Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
  annotations:
   cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  selector:
    app: test
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  type: ClusterIP
```

Ingress is

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "cert"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: "ip"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

However my ingress is UNHEALTHY with 5000 port in backend service

IP address  Health status   Port      Host vm
*******                 5000
*******                 5000

My service runs on 80 and docker container runs on 5000. I followed the instrucitons from this  link.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress

My goal is to run web application internal to my network not exposed to internet.

Ingress is showing UNHEALTHY

Comment: As you are using the annotation "[cloud.google.com/neg :](http://cloud.google.com/neg:) '{"ingress": true}'", can you check if you are using VPC-native clusters or shared VPC or GKE network policy in the environment.                                                                             Also,can you try using the below [annotations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#associating_backendconfig_with_your_ingress) 
"ingress.kubernetes.io/backends" in the “Ingress” Yaml file and "cloud.google.com/backend-config" in the “Service” Yaml file.

Comment: Have you also tried to create the proper firewall rules https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#create_a_firewall_rule ?

Comment: VPC-native traffic routing is Enabled in my cluster. 
@boredabdel In this firewall rule, container port I used is 5000 ( my docker container port) and what will be the source range of ip address? I have used the external ip address range of my cluster.

Comment: The answer below from Kiran has answers to your question

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment mentioned, you are using an **External IP address** range for a VPC native cluster but your goal is to run web applications **internal to your network** and not **expose** to the **internet**. In order to attain this, you can use Internal IP address range (Private IPs) instead of External IP address range (Public IPs) and create a [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#prepare-environment) rule accordingly for proxy-only subnet.

**Option 1 :**

You need to create [another firewall](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#ip-ranges) rule known as **ingress allow firewall** rule so that the traffic from Google Cloud probers can connect to your backends for health checks to work. Make sure to include the below source IP ranges (Probe source IP ranges) only in the firewall rule.

- 35.191.0.0/16
- 130.211.0.0/22

If you don't have **ingress allow firewall** rules that permit the health check, the implied deny rule blocks inbound traffic. When probers can't contact your backends, the load balancer considers your **backends** to be **unhealthy** and return HTTP 503 responses to clients when all backends are unhealthy.

You can follow the attached [example](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#firewall_rules) and create a firewall rule with a name **fw-allow-health-checks** and make sure to use the Probe source IP ranges only.

**Option 2:**

If the issue still persist, try to define the **target port** in the **Ingress** yaml file as shown below :

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 5000
```

Comment: I meant external to cluster not to external ip address to Internet.